# create-react-app aborting with code ENOENT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, create-react-app

Just started out with React using an online course from Udemy. For some reason my `create-react-app` stopped working all of a sudden and it shows this log.

```html
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Vahram\Desktop\Udemy-React\Personal-Notes\Sec5\pokedex-exercise\node_modules\postcss-normalize
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Vahram\Desktop\Udemy-React\Personal-Notes\Sec5\pokedex-exercise\node_modules\.postcss-normalize.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Vahram\Desktop\Udemy-React\Personal-Notes\Sec5\pokedex-exercise\node_modules\postcss-normalize' -> 'C:\Users\Vahram\Desktop\Udemy-React\Personal-Notes\Sec5\pokedex-exercise\node_modules\.postcss-normalize.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vahram\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-06T21_38_53_463Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting pokedex-exercise/ from C:\Users\Vahram\Desktop\Udemy-React\Personal-Notes\Sec5
Done.
```

I checked out similar questions on here and there were some solutions I tried. The usual answer is to delete `package.json` but I don't have that seeing as I'm trying to make a new React app. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Originally tried `npx create-react-app my_app`
2. Then tried running `npm install -g create-react-app` and then `create-react-app my_app`.
3. Then tried `npm cache clean --force` followed by `npm rebuild` then step 2 again.
4. Then tried `npm init --yes` to generate a `package.json` file, followed by trying to make a new app again using CRA.
5. Tried restarting the machine

Curious thing I noticed that I'm not sure is related to the issue:
When I go to Task Manager, there are two Node.js processes running. When I try to end one, it spawns another Node.js process... I can't get rid of all Node.js processes. This is why I originally restarted the machine.

Any help is appreciated! I have no idea how to proceed... I'm even thinking of formatting my machine and starting everything from scratch. However, I'd like to know why this happens so that I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: The error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename` is telling you that either the `rename` command is not anything that your OS knows about (but it comes with Windows so that should work) or the path given to `rename` doesn't exist, so: is this on a genuinely create attempt?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah, the command should be recognized (the whole thing was working just a day ago). Sorry, I don't understand the second part of your comment. I think you're asking if I'm running create-react-app with no prior configurations or anything like that? If so, yes. I'm just `cd`ing into the directory `C:\Users\Vahram\Desktop\Udemy-React\Personal-Notes\Sec5` and running either `npx create-react-app pokedex-exercise` or `create-react-app pokedex-exercise`.

Comment: @Kamermans no that's not what it says, it says that the rename operation failed with error ENOENT.

Comment: In my experience you get this issue when you have some other process watching the directory - for example VSCode. What is the command line of the node process that you see in task manager? (enable the command line column in the details grid to find out)

Comment: @CherryDT Just checked. For both of them it looks like a file location relating to Adobe Creative Cloud. It never interfered before though... I'm gonna try turning it off for a moment. 

Edit: Now I'm getting `npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I was also getting this sometimes before. It was either this error or `ENOENT`.

Comment: Are you sure you are creating a project from scratch with a name no other folders have? You might be creating your project on top of an existing one if the naming matches

Comment: @CherryDT I'm still getting the same error after quitting Adobe Creative Cloud and ending the two node.js tasks from the task manager. The error above was just by chance, I think... The same error persists.

Comment: @ale917k Just made a new desktop folder, `cd`ed into it, and tried a whole new name for an app I haven't tried before. It worked... So thank for that answer! But what's going on? There are no projects showing up in the file explorer in the folders I was trying to create it in before.

Comment: Glad that helped - I would think you are using windows and that the explorer indexing failed to update the folder you deleted, leaving "ghost" files still there causing that conflict you see upon installation. You could try with this solution: https://superuser.com/a/985100/1240469

Comment: Running Step 2 in your post fixed my problem, which otherwise sounded identical to your original question..

Answer (score 12):

I just solved this using the following command.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and then:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Regards

Comment: you beautiful humanbeing

Comment: Awesome! I have a new laptop and just installed some tools. Didn't even know that CRA is already there. It worked! I uninstalled and used npx to install again. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

While I may be a bit late to the conversation, I'd like to offer some guidance that could prove helpful, especially for newcomers. I've encountered a particular issue with the new create-react-app, and here's a solution to address it:

Step 1: Start by uninstalling the global create-react-app package using the command `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`.

Step 2: Next, reinstall the create-react-app globally by executing `npm install -g create-react-app`.

Step 3: Don't forget to close the Terminal window.

Step 4: Finally, initiate the creation of your new React application with the command `npx create-react-app my-app`.

These steps should assist you in resolving the issue you're facing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try reinstalling npx using
npm i -g npx

Answer (score -2):

only npm uninstall -g create-react-app and then, installer anyway version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).