# Error when create react project using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to create a new **React App** using the following command.

```bash
npx create-react-app ./
```

But, It throws the below error,

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\\Users\\TOSHIBA\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\\Users\\TOSHIBA\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\TOSHIBA\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\\_logs\\2023-07-30T04_29_09_680Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Check if this can help [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426349/create-react-app-aborting-with-code-enoent)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need an app name instead of a directory:

```
npx create-react-app <your-app-name>
```

If that doesnt work, you can either try elevated permissions or, preferably, change your npm install path to something your user has permissions for:

```
npm config set prefix <PATH_NAME>
```

If that doesnt work, ask yourself:

- Does the folder specified in the error exist?
- Did I install npm as a different user?
- What terminal am I using? (PowerShell, WSL, cmd)

That should give you some ideas where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app must include the app name, remove './' and mention the name of the app. Hope your error will be resolved then